# bash script checking open port | checking for specific string in output of command

Tags: bash

```
if [[ $(timeout 3 nc -zv 172.31.3.2 88) = *open* ]];then
        echo "Port Open"
else
        echo "Port Closed"
fi
```

I am trying to check if a port is open then it printing out port open if it is open.

I am using netcat to do that.

It should return something like: *[172.31.3.2] 88 (kerberos) open*.

I am trying to check for that *open* string in the output, then if it says that it will return *port open*

For some reason it just keeps returning this:

```
[172.31.3.2] 88 (kerberos) open
Port Closed
```

Comment: Only content written to _stdout_, not stderr, is captured by command substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing the output in the terminal, it's being written to `stderr`, since `stdout` is captured by the command substitution. So you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so you can capture it as well.

```
if [[ $(timeout 3 nc -zv 172.31.3.2 88 2>&1) = *open* ]];then
        echo "Port Open"
else
        echo "Port Closed"
fi
```